# Remove all strings of numbers of length 3 or 4 - SED

Tags: sed

I am trying to write an sed command that will mask all instances of length 3/4 numbers with '*' from a text file. I have this:

```
s/[0-9]\{4\}/\*\*\*\*/g
s/[0-9]\{3\}/\*\*\*/g
```

which will do it but also masks the first 3/4 characters from any longer numerical strings.

Is there a way to just mask the string of length 3 and 4. The numbers could be part of text also.

I am new to sed and have tried to read the documentation but am struggling to just remove the ones I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look for `\s` on either side of the numbers maybe

Comment: If a character exists after 3/4 number then u can use [^0-9] after }

Comment: I would say `s/([^0-9])[0-9]{3,4}([^0-9])/\1****\2/g` but unfortunately this doesn't work for sequences at the start or end of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't give any input example, try this, see if it helps:

```
sed -r 's/\b[0-9]{3}\b/***/g;s/\b[0-9]{4}\b/****/g' file
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "111
1234567
111 1111 12ab 1111a                                        
11 1111 1"|sed -r 's/\b[0-9]{3}\b/***/g;s/\b[0-9]{4}\b/****/g'
***
1234567
*** **** 12ab 1111a
11 **** 1
```

btw, do you really want to replace 3 numbers with **3** stars, 4 numbers with **4** stars?

**EDIT**:

```
sed -r 's/([^0-9]|\b)[0-9]{3}([^0-9]|\b)/\1***\2/g;s/(\b|[^0-9])[0-9]{4}(\b|[^0-9])/\1****\2/g' file
```

test (with OP's example)

```
kent$  echo "111
1234567
111 1111 12ab 1111a
11 1111 1
 fhdjs777ssaa"|sed -r 's/([^0-9]|\b)[0-9]{3}([^0-9]|\b)/\1***\2/g;s/(\b|[^0-9])[0-9]{4}(\b|[^0-9])/\1****\2/g'    
***
1234567
*** **** 12ab ****a
11 **** 1
 fhdjs***ssaa
```

note, this line will replace `foo123bar` with `foo***bar`, but will leave `foo123456bar` the same.

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot to give examples. The above works for all cases except the '1111a' - this would also need to be '****a'

Comment: Examples: e111 -> e*** 3333 -> **** 222 -> *** fhdjs777ssaa -> fhdjs***ssaa